# Select a class in a class and make it have its own line

Tags: html, css, tags

**How to to select a class with in a class? CSS**

*Need to Do:*
Select "fourthRow" in "buttons" and make the class appear on it's own line
Also, if anyone knows how to make this code more efficent it would be very much appreciated. Very wet code.

HTML:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
     <title>Calculator</title>
     <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    </head>
    <body>
    <div class="buttons">
     <div class="fourthRow">
      <div>
       <button class="7">7</button>
      </div>
      <div>
       <button class="8">8</button>
      </div>
      <div>
       <button class="9">9</button>
      </div>
      <div>
       <button class="divide">&#247;</button>
      </div>
     </div>
     <div class="thirdRow">
      <div>
       <button class="4">4</button>
      </div>
      <div>
       <button class="5">5</button>
      </div>
      <div>
       <button class="6">6</button>
      </div>
      <div>
       <button class="multiplicaton">x</button>
      </div>
     </div>
     <div class="secondRow">
      <div>
       <button class="1">1</button>
      </div>
      <div>
       <button class="2">2</button>
      </div>
      <div>
       <button class="3">3</button>
      </div>
      <div>
       <button class="subtract">-</button>
      </div>
     </div>
     <div class="firstRow">
      <div>
       <button class="0">0</button>
      </div>
      <div>
       <button class="dot">.</button>
      </div>
      <div>
       <button class="equal">=</button>
      </div>
      <div>
       <button class="add">+</button>
      </div>
     </div>
    
    </div>
    
    </body>
    </html>
```

.....................................................................

Comment: can you please elaborate "make the class appear on it's own line"

Comment: Sorry that was a little too brief, I basically mean all the buttons in fourthRow fall in its own line, and thirdRow falls below it on the page and so fourth

Comment: the issue is all the buttons are wrapped in a div and divs by default are block (meaning they occupy entire width of parent). Remove the wrapping div on the buttons and they will all be in one line

Comment: Also only related to your "how do I make this code better" question, avoid using numbers alone as classes like you have with `<button class="1">` etc. They [don't behave normally as selectors](https://benfrain.com/when-and-where-you-can-use-numbers-in-id-and-class-names/) that way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Select "xRow" in "buttons" and make the class appear on it's own line:

-

```
.fourthRow, .thirdRow, .secondRow, .firstRow {
  display: flex;
}
```